# Unabled to access locally hosted wcf service over the internet

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, network-protocols

Running wcf service on local machine and trying to connect from another machine by public IP address on specified port not LAN internal IP.
basically I wanted to make chat application without including any central server. client machine would be treat as a server like torrent.

Comment: Did you made a port forwarding on your router?

Comment: no, how can i do this?

Comment: That is most probably written in the manual of the router

Comment: do you have any sample code for this?

Comment: but how torrent and skype working as we never manuallly forworded any port.

Comment: Torrent & Skype first initiate the communication outbound. No rule needed. For accepting inbound you *need* a rule on the router

Comment: How do I automatically map port using NAT-PMP and/or UPnP?

Comment: could you pls explain me more, how can I do outbound communication?

Comment: Since you need to accept incoming communications, you will have to forward the necessary ports. Skype and torrents both manually initiate outbound communications, that's why they don't need to have a port forwarded for them.

Comment: @mason Is "initiate outbound communications" possible by c#? if possible then how?

Comment: Have you ever used the Webclient or HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes? You don't have to configure the firewall for those, because your computer is acting like a client and initiating the outbound traffic, that's why inbound traffic is allowed (because it's in response to your outbound connection).

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13285/Using-UPnP-for-Programmatic-Port-Forwardings-and-N

I was trying port forword by software then I've got an error as https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpea60jcdjlqzhu/PortForwordSoftwareError.JPG

I've tried as:

1. disabled/off the firewall
2. I'm using windows 8 o/s
3. I also have upnp enabled router image url: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbtqpkof7m3v4lp/IMG_20032014_161911.png

Comment: @mason I have done with upnp but if someone deactivated upnp on router then how it can be possible port forwarding?

KevinBrechbühl if you know something ?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really here to answer your questions about Port Fowarding, it's outside the scope of this site. Try looking at [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward the port from your router to the computer on your local network. That's because the router is in between your computer and the Internet, and so your router is actually the one with the Public IP.

There is [a site](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) that has good guides for forwarding ports on many different router models. Also check your router's manual if you still have it.

Comment: I've tried code but got an error:::

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in UPnPPortForwardManager.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: You can't configure the port forwarding from your application. You need to log into the router's web interface and configure it. The link I provided in my answer should explain the exact details for your particular router.

Comment: but I wanted to develop chat and file transfer application like skype and torrent, with router's web interface users would be worried. pepole will be ignore our application as we are giving long process to set up.

Comment: If the user is intended to host the chat server, then you'll just have to deal with it. When you configure server applications, you have to do some configuration at the network level in order to make those server applications available publicly. The other alternative is that your company hosts the server and their clients just connect to you. Then the only one who has to configure their network is you.